# A list of entries inside Playa tags

Tags: playa, relationships, structure

In the below I need the field `{link_rhs}` to display a link to any page or entry on the website. Previously we were using StructureFrame which was perfect for displaying pages, but it doesn't display all entries. Do I need the `{link_rhs}` field to also be a Playa field? How can a Playa field work within a Playa field? Or maybe another option?

```
{exp:playa:parents channel="rhs_cta" dynamic="off" entry_id='{embed:entry_id}'}
<article class="post">
    <figure>
        <a href="{link_rhs}">
            <img src="{thumbnail_image_rhs}" alt="{title}">
        </a>
        {if ribbon_title}<span class="green">{ribbon_title}</span>{/if}
    </figure>

    <div class="text">
        <h2><a href="{link_rhs}">{title}</a></h2>
        <p>{text_rhs}</p>
    </div>
    <hr class="desktop-version">
</article>
{if no_parents} 
    {embed="embeds/latest-blogs"}
{/if}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, `{link_rhs}` can be a Playa field, and can be displayed inside of the `playa:parents` loop. Just use the standard [fieldtype tag pair](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/field.html).

```
{link_rhs}
<a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}">
    <img src="{thumbnail_image_rhs}" alt="{title}">
</a>
{/link_rhs}
```

I use [comment_url_title_auto_path](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#comment-url-title-auto-path) here in case you're allowing entries from multiple channels )and hnce multiple URL structures) to be selected in the Playa field.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think a tag pair would work inside another like that, especially considering it's inside a Playa field. One problem, that URL is linking to the correct page URL but not the site URL... it's missing its parent page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, `playa:parents` is just an extended `channel:entries` class, with a modified query, so if it works in `channel:entries`, it should work in `playa:parents`. Re: URL - make sure your value for Comment Page URL is correct in each channel's Path settings.

Comment: The URL was incorrect in settings. Thank you very much your answer and comments!